# Equivalence of these two definitions of limit at a given point

Tags: analysis, epsilon-delta

Take a real $c$, a real $\delta > 0$, and a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
Then there are two definitions for $f$ to have a limit at $c$.

Definition 1: If there is a real $l$ such that
$$F(x) := f(x)$$
for all $0 < |x-c| < \delta$
and 
$$F(x) := l$$
for $x = c$
is continuous at $c$,
then the function $f$ has $l$ as the limit at $c$.

Definition 2: The normal epsilon-delta definition.

My question is: how to see they are equivalent?

Comment: As currently put, the two definitions are not equivalent.

Comment: In definition 1, don't you want to impose a special property that $F$ has at $c$? Also, what did you introduce $\delta$ for in the first sentence?

Comment: Sorry! I omitted to type out "is continuous at $c$"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in Def1. But I can say that the function $F$ defined by
\begin{equation}
F(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{rl}
f(x), &x\neq c\\
l,&x=c
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
is continuous at $c$ iff the limit of $f$ at $c$ is $l$

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post. Yes, but why?

Comment: Suppose $F$ is continuous then for all $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|F(x)-F(c)|<\epsilon$ which is equivalent $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$. This establishes $f$ has limit $l$ at $c$. Conversely if the limit of $f$ is $l$ at the point $c$ then for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$. Actually this is equivalent to say $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|F(x)-F(c)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not understand why "\delta" in the definition of $F$ has to be introduced?

Comment: You are right, I edited.